# Why java bitwise compliment not fliping properly?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I have the following code:

```
int b1 = 0b1011;
b1 = ~b1;
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(b1));
```

But I am not getting the expected result **i.e. 100**

What I am getting is `11111111111111111111111111110100`.

Can any one please explain about this?

Answer (score 4):

You are flipping an integer which consists of four bytes, i.e., 32 bits. The first 28 bits are initially 0. They are getting flipped, too, which results in the number that you get.
Before flipping:

```
b1 = 0b00000000000000000000000000001011
```

After flipping:

```
b1 = 11111111111111111111111111110100
```

In order to get rid of the unwanted 1's you could logically AND `b1` after flipping the bits:

```
b1 = ~b1
b1 = b1 & 0b1111
```

Answer (score 1):

You are ok
**0b1011** is the same as `00000000000000000000000000001011`
so inverting it is:

```
11111111111111111111111111110100
```

DO this to keep bits length:

```
int b1 = 0b1011;
b1 = ~b1;
b1 = b1 & 0b1111;
final String x = String.format("%4s", Integer.toBinaryString(b1)).replace(' ', '0');
System.out.println(x);
```

Comment: So any way I can remove this extra 1s?